# Finder search extension implementation

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, finder

Is there a possibility to write finder search extension that will provide all the data needed for  finder search. What I would like to achieve is to provide search result based on some query without need of going through all the directories.

Comment: What are you looking to provide that doesn't exist in the current Spotlight and Finder search queries?

Comment: Its about building the query response without going through all the directories. Spotlight/Finder are trying to iterate through all the paths while executing query I would like to avoid that and provide just the proper data

Comment: Spotlight (which is also used by the Finder) uses its database to match the search query.  If the files have not been indexed by something, you would need to look at the metadata for each item to see if it matches.